# Is there an Intrinsic instruction for result[i] += A[k] * sin(B[k] * C[i] + D[k])?

Tags: cpu, intel, intrinsics, instructions

I have a simple code line (64 bytes in form of 8 doubles - exactly [one i7 cache line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15333156/1973207)) in a for i loop which is nested in for k loop:

```
 result[i] += A[k] * sin(B[k] * C[i] + D[k])
```

I look around [intell intrinsics manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide) yet seem to be lost: how to query for such function?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that there is an intrinsic for the four-parameter operation `a * sin(b * c + d)`. This isn't a fundamental operation that a CPU is likely to have a dedicated instruction for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait a minute, is `i` or `k` in the inner loop?  Assuming `k` is constant for all `i`, then broadcast `A[k]` into a whole vector, with `_mm256_set1_pd(A[k])`, and same for the other array[k] operands.

---

As Raymond says, that's way to complex for a single instruction.  Even `sin()` isn't implemented in hardware (except for scalar the x87 version).  Intel's intrinsic guide lists some Intel library functions that only [Intel's SVML provides](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523792), not part of gcc / clang's `<immintrin.h>`.

---

Use [an FMA (`_mm256_fmadd_pd`)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VFMADD132PD:VFMADD213PD:VFMADD231PD.html) for `B[k] * C[i] + D[k]`, and pass that result to a vectorized `sin()` function, if you can find one.

Feed that result into another FMA for the `result[i] += A[k] * ...`.

This of course takes two 32B vectors with AVX.

AVX512 does 64B vectors, but is only available in Xeon Phi accelerator cards for now.

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW could you link `result[i] += A[k] * ...` intrinsics (at least for 32B)?

Comment: @DuckQueen: There's only one intrinsic for packed-double FMA, so there's nothing else to link.  The C compiler takes care of choosing between `VFMADD132PD` / `VFMADD231PD`.  There's also a `fmsub_pd` intrinsic, and [`_mm256_fnmadd_pd`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VFNMADD132PD:VFNMADD213PD:VFNMADD231PD.html) to negate the product (e.g. `d - b*c`).  Since all your operations are adds, you just need the same FMA inside and outside the sin().