# How to implement a cache friendly dynamic binary tree?

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures, binary-tree, cpu-cache

According to several sources, including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Methods_for_storing_binary_trees), the two most used ways of implementing a binary tree are:

1. **Nodes and pointers (or references)** where each node *explicitly* holds its children.
2. **Array** where the position of child nodes is given *implicitly* by the index of its parent.

The second one is obviously superior in terms of *memory usage* and *locality of reference*. However, it can lead to problems if you want to allow **insertions** and **removals** from the tree in such a manner that may leave the tree **unbalanced**. This is because the memory usage of this design is an exponential function of the tree depth.

Suppose that you want to support such insertions and removals. How can you implement the tree such that tree traversal makes good use of CPU caches.

I was thinking about making an object pool for the nodes and allocate them in an array. This way the nodes will be close together -> hence good locality of reference.

**But if the size of the node is the same as the size of the cache line, does this make any sense?**

If you have a L1 line size of 64 bytes and you access the first member of `std::vector<std::uint8_t>(64)`, you will possibly have the entire contents of the vector in your L1 cache. This means that you can access any element very quickly. But what if the size of the element is the same as the cache line size? Since the cache line is [likely not to be very different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15333156/1097451) for L1, L2, and L3 caches, there seems to be no way in which locality of reference can help here. Am I wrong? What else can be done?

Comment: "The second one is obviously superior in almost any sense" Apart from the cache thing - why?

Comment: @NeilButterworth That was a silly thing to write from me. I tried to make it more precise. Feel free to edit if you have some other suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps an std::deque rather than a std::vector (or array). _"typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays."_ from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque  Also review the performance of std::vector (will try and find this reference ) - Random inserts/deletes using std::vector vs std::list, the vector perform better up to 100,00 elements (approx)

Comment: Found it _"Modern C++: What You Need to Know - Herb Sutter"_ from about 46 mins into the presentation  https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are working on research on how to improve binary trees for cache access patterns, I feel this is an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) - what is the problem you are trying to solve? Why do you think binary trees are the best algorithm for your problem? What is the expected working set size?

If you are looking for a generic associative storage, there are multiple cache-friendly (other keywords: "cache-efficient", "cache-oblivious") algorithms, such as [Judy arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array), for which there is an [extensive explanation PDF](http://judy.sourceforge.net/doc/shop_interm.pdf).

If your working set size is small enough, and you only need ordered set of items, a simple ordered array may be enough, which could lead to another performance benefit - [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array).

In the end, to find out what's best for your use-case is to try and measure different approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Use a block allocator.

You have one or maybe a handful of contiguous memory "pools" from which you dole out blocks of a fixed size. It's implemented as a linked list. So allocation is simply

```
answer = head, 
head = head->next, 
return answer;
```

freeing is simply

```
tofree->next = head;
head = tofree;
```

If you allow more than one pool of course you need to write code to determine the pool, which adds a bit of complexity, but not much. It's essentially a simple memory allocation system.
Since all pool members are close together in memory, you get good cache coherence on small trees.  For large trees you'll have to be a bit cleverer.